# ExtJS multisort on specific value

Tags: sorting, extjs

I have a grid with columns like these:

Name | Status | createdBy | runningSince | extraInformation

I want my grid to be sorted `DESC` by status - no problem.
But is it possible to show the row of a specific value in `createdBy` on top, followed by the `DESC` sorted status-values?

In the docs I found `Ext.util.Sorter` but even with the listed example, I don't understand how to use this in my case.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution as I am in the same boat..example below is great if you are using buttons..I am struggling to find out how to trigger this without causing the store to reload multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this example: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/example/grid/multiple-sorting.html